# Copy Specific Columns from DB 1 To DB 2 on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have Two Instance of Node JS server which is handled By NGINX. First server is connect with MongoDB First Server i.e

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/db_primary', { useMongoClient: true });

While Second Node Js Server is Connect with MongoDB Second Serer i.e

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/db_secondary', { useMongoClient: true });

Actually, I have to Do some Heavy Calculations on DB and that the main reason I will divide my DB into Two Pieces.

Initially When I have One Server then if the backend is busy with calculations (Millions of Entries) at that time Server is completely freeze. So by the Separation There is now no freezing point of server.

My Question is How I can Copy the selected Columns on The entire Table form DB 1 And paste it to DB 2 with only Selected Columns.

```
Example:Database 1 


{
    _id: ObjectID(54815dfsfsd1f564168ad51a5s),
    a: 123,
    b: 768,
    c: 89.67,
    d: 8976,
    e: 45
  }..........upto 10 million entries
```

Now I want to Copy Only Column c & e from Database 1 to Database 2.

```
Expected Result: 
{
        _id: ObjectID(54815dfsfsd1f564168ad51a5s),
        c: 89.67,
        e: 45
}..........upto 10 million entries
```

And all these things are done by CronJob of Nodejs. I mean Not a manual task.

I am Newbie on MongoDB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's possible through db.getSiblingDB() and cursor.forEach() in MongoDB.

Comment: ,I have updated the answer according to your requirement, you can check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) with query. So, `db.collection.find({},{c:1,e:1})` and then insert that to second DB.

Inside the one DB you can do it with use of [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) with [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) stages.

Have you consider to use [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/index.html) and [secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/index.html) read?

Comment: I am trying to go with Replica Set. I think it would be better for me. Thanks, @JJussi for spending the time on my Query. Really Appreciate

Comment: You can always mark answer "right"..

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to Copy Only Column c & e from Database 1 to Database 2.

It's Only possible through `mongo shell` method like `cursor.forEach()` & `db.getSiblingDB()`. you can copy the one database collection some selected documents to the another database collection.

> My Question is How I can Copy the selected Columns on The entire Table
>   form DB1 And paste it to DB2 with only Selected Columns.

Let's start from beginning , suppose that you have two database `db1` & `db2`.

```
use db1
switched to db db1
```

I am going to create `collection` in `db1` having name `orders`

```
> db.createCollection("order")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Again i am going to insert some `documents` in **orders** `collection` in `db1`.

```
> db.orders.insertMany([
...  {       "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea525"),
...         "cust_id" : "A123",
...         "amount" : 500,
...         "status" : "A"
... },
... {
...         "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea526"),
...         "cust_id" : "A123",
...         "amount" : 250,
...         "status" : "A"
... },
... {
...         "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"),
...         "cust_id" : "B212",
...         "amount" : 200,
...         "status" : "A"
... },
... {
...         "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea528"),
...         "cust_id" : "A123",
...         "amount" : 300,
...         "status" : "D"
... }])
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea525"),
                ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea526"),
                ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"),
                ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea528")
        ]
}
```

In the above collection `orders` there is **4** documents , But i only want to copy some field records ( Suppose that here i want to **copy** "cust_id" : "B212" respective records to `db2`).

Again i am going to create second database `db2`.

```
> use db1
switched to db db2
```

Again i am going to create the collection `orders1` in `db2`.

```
> db.createCollection("order1")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

**Note :** Here for running the below mention query you have to switch to `db1`. because we are going to copy the collection records from `db1` to `db2`.

```
> use db1
switched to db db1
```

Then execute the below mention query

```
db.orders.find({"cust_id": "B212"}).forEach(function(d){db.getSiblingDB('db2')['orders1'].insert(d);});
```

For confirmation of copy of that records field has successfully done or not . You have to switch to `db2`. And find out the collection `order1` records in `db2`.

```
> use db2
switched to db db2

> show collections
orders1

> db.orders1.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"), "cust_id" : "B212", "amount" : 200, "status" : "A" }
>
```

Or through below command to find the records in proper format

```
> db.orders1.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a44c1479adf6e5fc5cea527"),
        "cust_id" : "B212",
        "amount" : 200,
        "status" : "A"
}
>
```

As above i have already said that only i want to copy the `"cust_id" : "B212"` records from `db1->orders` to `db2->orders1`.

**Note:** Here the **two databases** would need to share the same **mongod** for this to work.

For your further ref [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/) and [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

Comment: Thanks, @Md Haider Ali Khan for spending your precious time. Really Appreciate.

Comment: @Abhay, In my example i have taken 4 documents in a collection(For your better understanding). And among 4 documents only copy the one document records to second database collection.